# What are the downsides of repeating React higher-order components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's suppose that

1. You have a `List` component that iterates through a list of 10 posts and calls the `Post` component for each one.
2. You want to make the current route available to each `Post` component using React Router's `withRouter` higher-order component:

For example:

```
const List = ({posts}) => {
  return <div>{posts.map(post => <Post post={post} />)}<div> 
}
```

There are two possible patterns:

1. Wrap each `Post` with `withRouter`.
2. Wrap `List` with `withRouter` and pass `Router` as a prop to `Post`.

The first approach makes more sense logically (`withRouter` lives together with the component that uses its prop) but results in 10 `withRouter` wrappers in your virtual DOM.

Are there any downsides to this? Maybe from a performance standpoint? Or is it fine?

Comment: if you have to stick with these options, you should go with the second option. its going to be more efficient, the posts are by nature rendered by the list and you can pass that prop very easily. The only fallback is you need to ensure that if for some reason another component would render the Post you need to pass the withRouter prop.  That being said I wouldn't make each post call router methods. Rather i'd make a higher order component handle that routing and pass methods to call down to the children. this way you get consistent routing throughout the application.

Comment: Well, my question is about HoCs in general, so making a HoC to handle routing would just pose the same issue. When you say it's "more efficient", is that based on data, or just your preference?

Comment: the overhead of rendering each component wrapped with the router is more than when on the list. if your posts grew to a large number you could potentially see browser performance issues. Why not use browserHistory or something instead of a composed / wrapped component.

Comment: Just to clarify, my question is *not about routing*, I just used `withRouter` as an example. It could be any kind of HoC. So suggesting browserHistory is not very helpful…

Comment: sure, I'm just posing an alternative to a particular piece of functionality, since there is one. My other comments about which method to use still stands as is.

Answer (score 3):

In short: using higher orders components as-is may cause you to hit performance issues sooner, so you would have to do a bit of extra work to optimize for performance when you hit these problems.

The downside to your first option is that you would instantiate an extra component instance for every list item. Depending on the length of your list you would hit performance issues sooner. So what you want to do is reduce the number of component instances but not give up on the compasability HoC's give you.

Now Andrew Clark has given [a great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zD_judE-bXk) about HoC's and how he built [Recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) which provides utilities to "squash" HoC's with their child components, reducing the number of component instances and improve performance. As he mentions, squashing is possible if you are using functional components and if they don't access "context".

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any benchmarks to cite, but there was a really great talk about performance and React by Steve McGuire. https://youtu.be/5sETJs2_jwo?t=15m55s. I'd recommend watching the whole video, as he talks a lot about HOCs and performance in the context of super low-powered devices. The takeaway here is that they have extremely high performance goals on very constrained devices and are still using plenty of HOCs. Unless you are rendering very large datasets, or doing something where you're triggering way too many renders, you should be fine to wrap each `Post` in `withRouter`.